# What is the calculation for the distance VIPER can travel without recharging its batteries?

Tags: the-moon, rovers, solar-power, battery, nasa-viper

[VIPER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIPER_(rover)), the lunar rover NASA has developed to search for water in the permanently shadowed regions near the south pole of our Moon, will be equipped with (rechargeable) batteries to be able to drive, shine its lights and power its drill system.

Very likely it will use [radioisotope heater units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_heater_unit), like Spirit and Opportunity did, to keep the batteries and critical components and subsystems at an operating temperature.

The rover will have a size similar to a golf cart (around 1.4 m x 1.4 m x 2 m).

If we suppose a box with size ( 1 m x 1 m x 1 m ?) could have room for all the rechargeable (lithium-ion) batteries, how far could the rover drive then with one charge, taking into account the mass (200 kg ?), the [rolling resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance) of the wheels with the surface, and the gravity of the Moon.

This is a question about the feasibility of the VIPER !